# Adding a specific string to an object data with condition in object array

Tags: javascript

I have an object array where i'm trying to modify value if it starts with '//'. If the condition is met i want to add 'https:' before that. Then the value should be like 'https://'. I have done the following. Can't figure out where the problem is.

```js
var projects = [
{
    value: "//",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
},
{
    value: "//",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
}];
const string1 = "https:";
const objIndex = projects.findIndex(obj => obj.value.indexOf('/') === 0 ? obj.value === string1.concat(obj.value): obj.value === obj.value );console.log(objIndex);
```

Comment: You have multiple conception problems here: `findIndex` doesn't loop on all the array, it stops at the first item found. Aslo attributing a value is with `=`, not `===`. Also if you start a string by `'`, end it with `'`

Comment: I recommend to fix the source of the issue. Replacing `//` with `https://` is an assumption which might be correct as well as incorrect. Just store the protocol properly to avoid future issues.

Comment: @Satpal please don't fix a syntax error as an edit. The OP has to relize there was a mistake, correcting it silently can make the problem persist in the original code

Comment: @Kaddath, In my opinion, syntax error must have been introduced by OP when posting the question. As per the question description, I am sure syntax error was not his problem. Thanks for the advice though :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `value` property and then check whether the `value` column [startWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) the following signs `//`:

```
const result = projects.map(({value, ...rest}) => 
    ({ value: value.startsWith('//') ? `https://` : value, ...rest}))
```

An example:

```js
var projects = [
  {
value: "//",
label: "jQuery",
desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
  },
  {
value: "//",
label: "jQuery UI",
desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
  }];
const string1 = 'https:';
const result = projects.map(({value, ...rest}) => ({ value: value.startsWith('//') ? `https://` : value, ...rest}))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: OP wants to update `value` property value if it starts with `//`. `includes()` method will return true even when `//` is not at the start but anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in string variable definition, you use different quote characters here: `const string1 = 'https:";`
And you can create a new array with "reduce".

```js
let projects = [
{
    value: "//google.com",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
},
{
    value: "//",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
}];
let stringToReplace = "https:";
let objIndex = projects.reduce((arr, item) => (item.value = item.value.replace(/(\/\/.*)/, `${stringToReplace}$1`), arr.push(item), arr), []);
console.log(objIndex);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with a `.forEach()`:

```js
var projects = [
  {
    value: "//",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
  },
  {
    value: "//",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
  },
  {
    value: "http://",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
  }];

const str = 'https:';
const target = '//';
projects.forEach(p => { if (p.value === target) { p.value = str + target } })

console.log(projects)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```
projects.forEach((obj) => {
  if (obj.value === '//') {
    obj.value = 'https://';
  }
});
```